# Using Microsoft Word to open *.docx in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

After doing some research, it seems that you can use Word Interlop to manipulate Word document (Open, modify, change etc.). Like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application ap = new Application();

        Document doc = ap.Documents.Open(@"C:\temp\TestDoc.docx");
        doc.Activate();
    }
}
```

But doing it that way, the MS word application itself with the GUI are not showing. I suspect it does not get started at all. I can only see `WINWORD.EXE` in the Processes tab of the Windows Task Manager but not in Applications tab.

What I want to do is:

1. Starting the MS Word application
2. open the document
3. Show it to the end user, so they can modify/save it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Ryan, much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with using Office Interop, then I think you can get what you're looking for by setting the `Visible` property of the `Application` instance to true after you open the document.

```
ap.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Cool Trick, thanks. I tried `ap.Documents.Open` with `Visible: true` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you need to control Word application simple [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.100).aspx) may be enough:

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\temp\TestDoc.docx")
```

Comment: Those solutions relay on Word is associated with *.docx, what happened if there is not such association at all (including OpenOffice), or Word is not installed. Any exceptions I need handle?

Comment: @PaulL, I don't think you get notified if shell found handler for the file type or not... Eric (+1) have the answer you are looking for anyway.

Comment: Thanks Alexei. Your answer is very straight forward and simple, I pick Eric's solution because it is seems more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) instead.

That's all you need here and will produce the behavior you're after.